# Ruby on Rails - Validate attribute with Associated Model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  has_many: :model_b
end

class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: :model_a
end
```

Both models have `star_date` and `end_date`, I want to validate de `ModelB` dates to be between the `ModelA` dates. Something like this:

```
class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: :model_a
  validates :start_date, after_date: ModelA.start_date
end
```

I'm new to Rails, and I have no clue how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/performing-custom-validations-in-rails-an-example-9a373e807144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add custom validation

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :model_b
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to : model_a
  validates :is_between_parent_period

  private

  def is_between_parent_period
    unless start_date.between?(self.model_a.start_date, self.model_a.end_date) && end_date.between?(self.model_a.start_date, self.model_a.end_date)
      errors.add(:base, 'Must be between parent start date and end date')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A check if two date or time ranges A and B overlap needs to cover a lot of cases:

```
A partially overlaps B
A surrounds B
B surrounds A
A occurs entirely after B
B occurs entirely after A
```

to do simple check for overlap you can create method in model A, and then passed the other model (model b) as parameters

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :model_b

  # Check if a given interval overlaps this interval    
  def overlaps?(other)
    (self.start_date - other.end_date) * (other.start_date - self.end_date) >= 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer is useful, I'll  use this code on my validation. Thanks.